# Removed item from Adapter not rearanged

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm making an app that adds to a cart a bunch of items, now, I have this UI that adds an item with the + button and deletes it from the array if I press the - button when 1 is at the quantity.

I have an array of items (ITEM A, ITEM B), I can add quantity to these items, so I have created a second array that stores the item name, the item quantity, and the item price, I do this to have a basic cart with the items I have selected.

So, when I press the + button quantity increases on my item A, the same as Item B, this works properly, but now when I click the minus button - and the quantity is at 1, I remove that item from the selecteditem array, so now I have item b with a quantity of 3 but since I removed item a from that array, now item B is at position 0, that means that when I press item A to update its value, it will be updating the value of Item B and item A will be created at position 2, where item b is, so when I update item bit will update item A and this continues

[image]

this is the code I use to update the values of the item

### Adapter

```
var productList = mutableListOf<Product>()
 var cartProductList = mutableListOf<ProductCartSelected>()


 inner class StoreViewHolder(itemView: View): BaseViewHolder<Product>(itemView){
        override fun bind(item: Product,position: Int) {
            //First button click before select quantity
            itemView.btn_action_add.setOnClickListener {
                itemView.btn_action_add.visibility = View.GONE
                itemView.card_selector_product.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                itemClickListener?.onCartClick(item)
            }

            itemView.btn_increase.setOnClickListener {
                val currentQuantity = itemView.txt_quantity.text.toString().toInt()
                if(currentQuantity != 20){
                    val quantity = currentQuantity + 1
                    display(quantity)
                    updateProductQuantity(position,quantity)
                }
            }

            itemView.btn_decrease.setOnClickListener {
                val currentQuantity = itemView.txt_quantity.text.toString().toInt()
                if(currentQuantity == 1){
                    removeSelectedProduct(position)
                }else{
                    val quantity = currentQuantity - 1
                    display(quantity)
                    updateProductQuantity(position,quantity)
                }
            }

        }

  fun setItems(selectedProductList: MutableList<Producto>) {
        productList = selectedProductList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun setProductSelected(productCartSelected: ProductCartSelected){
        cartProductList.add(productCartSelected)
    }

    fun removeSelectedProduct(position: Int){
        cartProductList.removeAt(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun updateProductQuantity(position: Int,quantity:Int){
        cartProductList[position].quantity = quantity
        itemClickListener?.onUpdatedProductQuantity(cartProductList[position])
    }
```

So, basically the problem is when I use  `removeSelectedProduct(position)` since it will remove the product on cartProductList but will keep references to the productlist indexes, so when updating the quantity on any other item, all indexes changed and the update is wrong

From my view, I sent the item a, and item B with `setItems()` method

### Data classes

```
@Parcelize
data class Product(
    val name:String = "", val price:Int = 0,val productImage:String = "",val hasDiscount:Boolean = false
) : Parcelable

data class ProductCartSelected(var quantity:Int,var productName: String,var price: Int)
```

If any other info is needed just ask me

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I program in java but I had the same problem. I suggest you create a single list that you use to populate your recyclerview. instead of just passing productname to your `ProductCartSelected` class why not pass it the product itself? and just for good measure I would give it an ID as well.

as you will only be using one list this should solve your problem as the positions in your recyclerview and your `ProductCartSelected` list should remain in sync.

Alternatively create a method that uses something like the ID I proposed to check the correct position of the items you are modifying before you modify them. but I would first try it with the previous approach

create a method that loops through the list of ProductCartSelected objects and returns the one object you are actually modifying lets call this method `fun ProductCartSelected findCartObject(cartId: Int)` (as I said sadly I dont speak kotlin) the in your OnBindViewHolder instead of passing the position to methods such as `updateProductQuantity` you will pass it a cartID (or alternatively a productName) and internally this method will use the findCartObject method in order to return the right object that should actually be modified.

Comment: because passing the first list will have many attributes that the cart will not use, and this is a bad practice to pass data that will be never used, instead I just want to pass the data that I will receive at my cart, no more, no less

Comment: in that case use my second approach. instead of passing a position to to methods such as updateProductQuantity pass it something unique to that  ProductCartSelected object such as an ID (but I guess productName also works assuming you dont allow duplicates) ill add some code above

Comment: ID sounds good , like having a hashmap that corresponds each id with the item when deleted

Comment: hashmap is even better if you know your way around it just create a hashmap of ProductCartSelected objects and use it to generate the list that populates your recyclerview. after that you just make all modifications using the key. personally I have never used a Hashmap for this but I have thought about it so let me know how it goes.